# JavaScript/Express Promise.all() issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, postman

I am creating a simple movie discussion forum. The user has a profile where they can enter in their favourite films separated by a comma. The backend route calls the OMDB API and returns the JSON objects for the movies which the details such as poster, title and other applicable information will be shown.

I have created a backend route using Express to get the information. I successfully managed to get a single movie from OMDB and return it as a JSON object on Postman.

However, when I try to map through the favouriteFilms array, the object returned is (or seems to be) empty.

The code below makes a get request to '/movies', takes in the auth JWT middleware created and an async req, res callback.

A profile variable is declared to get the profile of the user by id.

Using `Promise.all()`, a films variable is set to map through all the `profile.favouriteFilms` array and for each film, return the information from the OMDB request and then `res.json(films.data)`

```
router.get('/movies', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

    const films = Promise.all(
      profile.favouritefilms.map((film) =>
        axios.get(
          `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${film}&apikey=${config.get('OMDBkey')}`
        )
      )
    );
    res.json(films.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

As stated above, the output on Postman is empty.

Comment: `films = Promise.all(...)` ---> `films = await Promise.all(...)`

Comment: ^ That will still not magically set a `data` property on `films` though.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think response returned from `axios.get(...)` has a `data` property.

Comment: @Yousaf Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle result of Promise.all by another .then() method. See below:

```
const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

const films = Promise.all(
  profile.favouritefilms.map((film) =>
    axios.get(
      `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${film}&apikey=${config.get('OMDBkey')}`
    )
  )
).then(films => res.json(films.map(film => film.data))
```

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` and `.then()`

Comment: Okay Dmytro that has worked thanks for that heaps. @Andreas, do you have an alternative at all?

Comment: @MatthewRook Other than to not mix `async`/`await` and `.then()`? Use one or the other. And if you really need a pre-made answer see the comment of Yousaf.

Comment: @andreas I tried Yousaf's solution. It didn't work. I don't have await on the Promise.all(), just to get the profile

Comment: @MatthewRook if this answer helped you. pls mark it as an answer.

Comment: @MatthewRook Only problem in your code is that you are not waiting for the promise to settle which can be done by either using `then()` method as shown in this answer or by using `await`.

Comment: Fantastic thanks yousaf! See, there are some nice people around. Stay safe mate